# Basic Straight-forward Tomcat-MySQL Link

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I have been trying for several weeks now in trying to get a very basic straightforward link between an Apache Tomcat 7 server and MySQL 5 working, but to no avail:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/MySQL"
```

This is what my server.xml currently looks like:

```
<Server>
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="30000"/>
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="" workDir="temp">
                <Context path="" docBase="www">
                    <Resource name="jdbc/MySQL" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="server" password="server" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/common" maxActive="15" maxIdle="3"/>
                </Context>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

And this is what's inside the web.xml file:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet><servlet-name>default</servlet-name><servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param><param-name>debug</param-name><param-value>0</param-value></init-param>
        <init-param><param-name>listings</param-name><param-value>false</param-value></init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet><servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name><servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param><param-name>fork</param-name><param-value>false</param-value></init-param>
        <init-param><param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name><param-value>false</param-value></init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config><session-timeout>30</session-timeout></session-config>
    <mime-mapping><mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
        <extension>png</extension>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping><mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <extension>htm</extension>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping><mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
        <extension>css</extension>
    </mime-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <Context>
        <ResourceLink name="jdbc/MySQL" global="jdbc/MySQL" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    </Context>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a classpath problem.

Your `mysql-connector-java-*.jar` should be in your `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` folder. Look for the "[MySQL DBCP Example" in the official How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html):

OR

declare your mysql jdbc jar file in your `CLASSPATH` variable like this:
    `SET CLASSPATH=c:\mysql\mysql-connector-java-3.0.8-stable-bin.jar;`

If it doesn't work, please provide the tutorial you are following and where are your configuration files.

Comment: It wasn't the MySQL jar causing it, it was a missing tomcat-dbcp.jar. But thanks a million for putting me on the right track.

Er...I know I shouldn't be making deviations from the original topic, but just to ensure I understand I am doing all this correctly and optimally, should I use the "short-form tags" in my JSP pages or not?